# Using ANY inside HAVING clause in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I've the following schema :

```
CREATE TABLE author(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE article(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  rating    NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  author_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES author
);

CREATE INDEX ON article(author_id);
```

I would like to fetch all authors and their top 5 articles if there exists atleast one article of the author with rating > 4.

It was tempting to write this:

```
SELECT au.id AS author,
       json_agg(ar.*) AS articles
FROM
    author au
JOIN LATERAL
  (SELECT *
   FROM article
   WHERE author_id = au.id
   ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 5) ar ON (TRUE)
GROUP BY au.id
HAVING any(ar.rating) > 4;
```

While `any(ar.rating) > 4` looks like a filter expression on each group, `any(ar.rating)` is not an aggregated value. So, it seems reasonable for Postgres to reject this query. Is it possible to write the query with `HAVING`?

As an alternative, I write this query to fetch the results :

```
SELECT au.id AS author,
       json_agg(ar.*) AS articles
FROM
  (SELECT au.*
   FROM author au
   WHERE EXISTS
       (SELECT 1
        FROM article
        WHERE rating > 4 AND author_id = au.id)) au
JOIN LATERAL
  (SELECT *
   FROM article
   WHERE author_id = au.id
   ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 5) ar ON (TRUE)
GROUP BY au.id;
```

This however doesn't combine both the grouping and checking for the existence of an article with rating > 4 in a single step. Is there a better way to write this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on using `ANY` you have to use `array_agg` to aggregate that column into an array.

```
HAVING 
  4< ANY(Array_Agg(ar.rating))
```

But if any is higher than 4 it also means that the maximum is higher that 4 so more readable will be

```
HAVING
  4 < Max(ar.rating)
```